# windows zmq dll issue for php 7.2

Tags: php, dll

I have XAMPP (x86) with PHP 7.2. I am trying to install ZMQ in the following way:

1. Downloaded (php_zmq-1.1.3-7.2-ts-vc15-x86.zip) file from https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/zmq/1.1.3/
2. extracted the zip file and copied `php_zmq.dll` file to `C:/xampp/php/ext` and libzmq.dll file to C:/xampp/
3. in the php.ini file, I added `extension=php_zmq.dll` and restarted my apache.

but I am getting the following error:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_zmq.dll' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_zmq.dll (The specified module could not be found.), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_zmq.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0

Please help me fix this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

libzmq.dll need to be in xampp/apache/bin/ folder for it to be load the extension.

Comment: I do confirm - that helped. Win10, WAMP, PHP 7.4.9. CGI or Apache Module mode - no matter, works both. Libs used from next link (files in archive should not be renamed) https://github.com/zeromq/php-zmq/issues/193#issuecomment-605456811